# SignalR websockets connection not working

Tags: signalr

When I hit the index page, SignalR tries to communicate with the server over websockets -- great! Sadly, none of the requests ever get through, and the websocket times out 5 second later without fail, after which it falls back to another protocol and begins working.

```
[15:36:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22api%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3'. jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js:8
[15:36:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://xxx/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=J4E8avsT4D%2BUrtfdAKgYufE%2B9pdPiYy5VHPqDP1qKa1DN%2FSAXkykC0B9N6VKWZxUM3UWnfoHmFtqU2nMKVW%2FNoCUIvYilyz2S1Yg%2FpsGrMHIlj0GaGCAW2BHeK9XsgI1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22api%22%7D%5D&tid=6'. jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js:8
[15:36:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened. jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js:8
[15:36:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: webSockets timed out when trying to connect.
```

I'm completely stumped as to what's going on. As far as I can tell, everything has been set up correctly. Below are my configuration settings.

Setup:

- Windows Server 2012
- IIS 8
- IIS Websockets Installed
- .NET 4.5

Packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.2.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried testing your SignalR app from localhost? It could be routers/firewalls/proxies/etc... blocking WebSocket requests. If that's the case you should try enabling TLS/SSL for WebSockets. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Proxy_traversal

Comment: I don't know what's blocking it, but you're totally right, it works from localhost. There's no Firewall (Windows Firewall is disabled), and the machine is just on the LAN, so I'm not sure what could be stopping it, but at least this gives me a place to start.

Comment: Proxies and hardware (switches/routers/proxies/firewalls) can all interfere with WebSockets... that may explain it...

Comment: @TomJacques Did you ever figure this one out? In my scenario I can get one computer to reproduce and the other will not. Both have Chrome Frame installed.

Comment: @styfle Unfortunately no. I tried on several different machines, and it looked like a problem specific to one of them. I "fixed" this by simply not using websockets (crappy fix).

Comment: @TomJacques, did you find its solution ? I am looking for one to one chat using `signalr`. I found one sample project using `long polling` but its not working. Can you please help me ?

Comment: It might be need self signed certificate the same issue was resolved once in node.js